# dlopen error - Undefined symbol error

Tags: qt, ubuntu-16.04

I've compiled the library via Qt, it compiled successfully ,but when I ldd the library, I got an this: `error: undefined symbol`. Most errors are linked to my classes.

I find some solutions,but none of them worked.

Here is the error output:
[image].

Comment: Are you sure that the library headers file you are including in your application are up-to-date? Maybe you are using an old version of them, or you just need to clean and rebuild everything.

Comment: sorry for a so long time, i tried clean and rebuild , it still shows the same error

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer, the code was run in windows before, i moved it to linux, the virtual class like

```
#ifndef _CO_COMMUNICATION_H
#define _CO_COMMUNICATION_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class CCommunicationInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~CCommunicationInterface()=0;//this is the error
    virtual bool Send(const vector<byte>&  Data) = 0;
    virtual bool Receive(vector<byte> &InBuf) = 0;
    virtual bool Open(bool IsBackUpComm, wstring& ErrorMsg) = 0;
    virtual bool Close() = 0;
    virtual bool IniParam(pointer Param, wstring& ErrorMsg) = 0;

};

typedef CCommunicationInterface* (*PFN_COMMUNICATION_INTERFACE)();
typedef void (*PFN_RELEASE_COMMUNICATION_INTERFACE)(CCommunicationInterface* lpObj);

#endif
```

then create a class based on CCommunicationInterface can Compile in windows successfully. but in linux it's shows the error.
so, i changed the code for this `

```
class CCommunicationInterface
    {
    public:
        virtual ~CCommunicationInterface(){}
        virtual bool Send(const vector<byte>&  Data) =0;
        virtual bool Receive(vector<byte> &InBuf) =0;
        virtual bool Open(bool IsBackUpComm, wstring& ErrorMsg) =0;
        virtual bool Close()=0;
        virtual bool IniParam(pointer Param, wstring& ErrorMsg)=0;

    };
```

then i got ldd -r lib NoError,
the
Analytic function's Error.